# Intersection of an uncountable number of almost sure events is almost sure?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I know that an intersection of a countable number of almost sure events is almost sure. We can show this using De Morgan's laws. My question is whether an intersection of an uncountable number of almost sure events is also almost sure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The intersection $\bigcap_{x\in [0,1]}([0,1]\setminus\{x\})=\emptyset$. The sets $[0,1]\setminus\{x\}$ have measure $1$ for the Lebesgue measure (probability). But $\emptyset$ has length zero.

Comment: I would also add the caveat for @master_goon that the intersection of an uncountable number of events may not give them a measurable event, i.e. the probability of the intersection may not even be defined! We normally define probability on a $\sigma$-algebra of events, which means it is closed for countable unions and intersections, but may well not be closed for uncountable ones.